# Build dict from list of pairs that is made from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, walrus-operator

Say we have a string like

```py
s = "a=b&c=d&xyz=abc"
```

I would like to get dictionary

```py
{"a": "b", "c": "d", "xyz": "abc"}
```

This is one way how to achieve this:

```py
dict([item.split("=") for item in s.split("&")])
```

This using generator is a bit better

```py
dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split("&"))
```

Is there some more elegant way? I tried this to take advantage of new walrus operator but it does not looks any better:

```py
{(pair := item.split("="))[0]: pair[1] for item in s.split("&")}
```

EDIT: I am looking for something single pass, without creating temporary list, or even one or more temporary tuples per item. Just building the `dict` directly... Would there be something along these lines?

Answer (score 1):

From your example,

`d = {u.split('=')[0]:u.split('=')[1] for u in s.split('&')}.`

Comment: walrus removes the necessity of one split, anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
s = "a=b&c=d&xyz=abc"

lst = [z for y in s.split("&") for z in y.split("=")]
    
dct = {lst[i]: lst[i+1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}

dct
```

output:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'xyz': 'abc'}
```

Comment: @RomanPavelka, is this your answer or not?

Comment: I am looking for something single pass, without creating temporary list, or even one or more temporary tuples per item. I will add this to the question description. I upvoted your answer because I had not knew double `for` in list comprehension before...